# A wild empty window appeared randomly. Can you help me deal with it?

Tags: windows-7

Today I had this weird empty window pop up and I don't know what it is, where it comes from, what it does nor how to get rid of it. It's just an empty window with only the title bar showing, but an empty title, in the old Windows style.

It looks like this:
[image: It looks like this]

Any ideas how I can find out more about this window? Right-clicking on it does nothing. I can move it, it's always on top of all other windows.

I'm using Windows 7 64 Bit.

Comment: Its nearly impossible to find out. I would open task manager, kill every process until the window disappears. Then reboot the computer (so everything comes back, and kill that process again just to be sure its that process.) Then search on the internet for the filename.

Comment: @LPChip "nearly impossible"? Use Process Explorer's "Find Window's Process" feature

Comment: @DavidPostill oh, interesting feature. Wasn't aware of that one.

Comment: @DavidPostill Awesome tip. I'd mark it as accepted answer, if you had posted it as such. I was able to find out the window comes from `ipmgui.exe`, which is an application belonging to Avira antivirus. I'm not exactly sure, what it is for, but maybe it's the advertisement window that usually pops up in the bottom right. Maybe it got bugged today somehow. At least I know now it's neither malicious nor important. Thank you.

Comment: @neon. Thanks. I would have posted an answer but it's already in the duplicate question. You can agree with the duplicate question proposal,